# How do I remove these closet sliding doors

Tags: removal, closet

I want to take these closet doors off but I’ve tried everything and they won’t come off. There’s no space to lift it up or angle and take the bottom track out first. i’ve also tried to take out the bottom track but it’s attached to the wood.

Bottom track:

[image: bottom track]

Top track:

[image: top track]

Comment: It's a little difficult to see detail in those small photos. Have you tried the adjuster screw to see if that will allow anything to detach?

Comment: the bottom spring-loaded peg slides up, allowing the door to be swung into the closet from the bottom, after which a small uplift will unseat the top track.

Answer (score 1):

Sliding closet doors that are mounted to rollers and suspended from a track are meant to be removed by pushing the door bottom into the closet space while lifting the rollers from the track. Be sure that the floor guide (if any) has been removed first.

If there are two doors (one in front and the other behind) you will need to remove the rearward door first and than the front one.

Comment: The white plastic piece at the bottom of the door first needs to be pulled up to disengage it from the track.